# Finding an infinite set of irrational numbers between two given numbers.

Tags: elementary-number-theory, irrational-numbers, decimal-expansion

I’m trying to do a question which asks: ‘find an infinite set whose elements are irrational numbers between $0$ and $0.0001$’

I understand that there are infinite irrational numbers between any two given real numbers, but can’t think of a way to come up with a specific set and put it into set notation.

Any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: Do you know if $\pi/100000$ is rational or irrational? How about $(\pi+1)/100000$?

Comment: Multiply the larger number by $\sqrt{2}/n$ for $n\geq 2$.

Comment: Alternative $\displaystyle \left(\sqrt{2} - 1\right) \times 10^{-n} ~: ~n \in \Bbb{Z_{\geq 4}}.$

Comment: The title asks about finding rational numbers, while the body discusses a need to find irrational numbers. Is it a mistake (in the title?) or did you simply omit describing a connection between them?

Comment: No matter if you want to show the existence of infinite many rational numbers , irrational algebraic numbers or transcendental numbers in the given range, you can take any positive real number that is of the desired type and divide it by a sufficient large positive integer to get infinite many solutions immediately.